# How do I add translation to custom templates in odoo 15

Tags: report, odoo, translation, odoo-15

In odoo 15 I have created a custom layout template for an invoice report (PDF). This template contains some texts in German language. Where do I have to specify any translation of these texts so they are considered if the invoice is printed in e.g. English?

Answer (score 0):

Activate debug mode.

1. You can find it in settings > translations > Transleted terms, and you search for your germans terms for translate them one by one.
2. You can set your template manually, settings > Technical > Email templates
   and now you can edit the template. But this is a non-dynamic solution.

More dynamic way :

3. Use .po,.pot files in your custom modules. if you have computed strings in your template use the function "_" before.
   Ex :

```
my_str = _("Hello, how are you")
```

afterwards, edit the '.po' file

Look at the documentation here:
https://www.odoo.com/documentation/16.0/developer/howtos/translations.html

Regards,